# How do I play back CENC-encrypted MP4 video using the HTML5 <video> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, video, encryption

I'm trying to play a video that I've CENC-encrypted using MP4box with these options:

```
MP4Box -crypt drm_file_gpac_clear.xml BigBuckBunny.mp4 -out BigBuckBunny_cenc.mp4
```

Where the XML file specifies clearKey encryption. It's taken from GPAC's website https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/encryption/common-encryption/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GPACDRM type="CENC AES-CTR">
<DRMInfo type="pssh" version="1" cypherOffset="9" cypherKey="0x6770616363656E6364726D746F6F6C31" cypherIV="0x00000000000000000000000000000001">
<BS ID128="0x6770616363656E6364726D746F6F6C31"/>
<BS value="2" bits="32"/>
<BS ID128="0x279926496a7f5d25da69f2b3b2799a7f"/>
<BS ID128="0x676cb88f302d10227992649885984045"/>
<BS bits="8" string="CID=Toto"/>
<BS ID128="0xccc0f2b3b279926496a7f5d25da692f6"/>
<BS ID128="0xccc0f2b3b279926496a7f5d25da692d6"/>
</DRMInfo>
<CrypTrack trackID="1" IsEncrypted="1" IV_size="16" first_IV="0x0a610676cb88f302d10ac8bc66e039ed" saiSavedBox="senc">
<key KID="0x279926496a7f5d25da69f2b3b2799a7f" value="0xccc0f2b3b279926496a7f5d25da692f6"/>
</CrypTrack>
</GPACDRM>
```

To play this back, I have an HTML file which includes:

```
<video  autoplay id="video1" controls src="BigBuckBunny_cenc.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

And JS:

```
var KEY = new Uint8Array([
  0xcc, 0xc0, 0xf2, 0xb3, 0xb2, 0x79, 0x92, 0x64,   // this is key for MP4 file
  0x96, 0xa7, 0xf5, 0xd2, 0x5d, 0xa6, 0x92, 0xf6    // encrypted with drm_file_gpac_clear.xml
]);

var config = [
  {
    initDataType: "cenc",
    videoType: "video/mp4",
  }
];

var video = document.getElementById('video1');
video.addEventListener('encrypted', handleEncrypted, false);
```

Plus other code which isn't relevant here, because my problem is that the 'encrypted' event isn't fired.

This plays fine if I put an unencrypted file in place of the encrypted one, and it also plays fine if I substitute a WEBM file from http://simpl.info/eme/clearkey/ and change the key and config accordingly ("view page source" on that URL for the details). So it *will* play back an encrypted file (in this case the 'encrypted' event is fired, of course), but not one I've encrypted with MP4box.

I've tried it in IE 11.0.9600.18036, Firefox 41.0, Chrome 45.0.2454.93 m and Chrome 47.0.2516.0 canary (64-bit).

I had a look at the MP4 file with MP4 Explorer, and it has the boxes I've been told to expect, such as encv, sinf and schm.

I've only been trying to learn about CENC during the last few weeks so this is all comparatively new, and I may have made some obvious mistake. If anyone can help, I'd be grateful for any advice.

Comment: It seems your code can actually play back a CENC encrypted video as you have proved by using the WEBM file from simple.info. It' possible your code has some issue with MP4 but it seems more likely that the problem is with the CENC encryption step. Are you able to share a link to the video?

Comment: Can you give us the content of chrome://media-internals/? When the file is loaded it should say "video_decoder DecryptingVideoDecoder". If it doesn't then the browser doesn't detect it as a encrypted stream.

Answer (score 0):

I put the same question on https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues/265 (a GPAC/MP4box forum) and got this reply from rbouqueau

> I don't have time right now to make a detailed answer but it can work.
>   You should be able to find examples from other people here on github
>   or on our previous sourceforge tracker/forums.
>
> What is wrong in your case is the encryption scheme: you are using a
>   GPAC specific one, whereas you probably mean to use ClearKey or
>   Widevine/Playready depending on the platform you are targetting.

This seems correct, as far as it goes. I thought the xml file was using ClearKey because of the comment in the original file:

Anyway it isn't, so I've been looking for an equivalent file that uses ClearKey.

These may help:

googlegroups.com/a/chromium.org/group/graphics-dev/attach/dcaad1f1cb85e3eb/Clearkey_encryption_using_MP4BOX.pdf

html5.cablelabs.com/mse-eme/doc/creation.html

dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/ff10d356cc07/encrypted-media/cenc-format.html
(see section 4)

However, I haven't yet got it to work ... but hopefully the above may still help anyone else with this problem.